# Dynamic Related List Not Supporting Custom Actions?

Tags: custom-button, related-list, action

I created a new dynamic related list - single as it satisfies my requirements which includes renaming my related list and filtering/showing only specific records. However, my custom actions do not show at all when trying to search it for the Actions part. Currently, it only lists New and Change Owner which are Standard actions.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to add my custom actions?

[image]

Comment: Is the action a List Button? Because only List buttons can be shown in related list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **cannot** add **custom action** on the related list.

Review the bellow idea : [Allow quick action on related lists](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfKBUAZ/allow-quick-action-on-related-lists)

However, you can use a **custom button** on the related list (Display Type : **List Button**).

[image]

And then it will be **available** on your **Actions** for **Dynamic related list**.

[image]

Comment: Looks like with Winter 24 quick actions will be generally available for this component type 